# GraphQL Server Cannot Be Reached Status Code 500

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

When attempting to use GraphQL Playground, it seemed like a cached version of schema.graphql was being referenced. So, I went ahead and ran `php artisan cache:clear`, which resulted in an error of "Server cannot be reached" and '"error": "Response not successful: Received status code 500"'.

I tried running `php artisan cache:config`, but that didn't resolve the issue.

I'm expecting to be able to connect, but it doesn't seem to want to connect. Connecting wasn't an issue prior to running `php artisan cache:clear`, just that any attempts to write a query seemed to reference the old schema.graphql, which isn't expected.

Comment: Try to manually delete bootstrap/cache/services.php and packages.php and retry

Comment: No effect. Still the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear lighthouse's schema cache you need to run `php artisan lighthouse:clear-cache`. You can check it on lighthouse documentation https://lighthouse-php.com/master/performance/schema-caching.html

For local development I prefer to disable the schema caching, setting the local environment variable `LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_ENABLE` to false.

Comment: Thank you! I see a whole host of good artisan commands for lighthouse when running php artisan. I appreciate your help.